# Points That I an failing to understand about "The Human Operators" by Harlan Ellison and A. E. van Vogt

Tags: short-stories, harlan-ellison

There are a couple details in this story that seem to just go over my head.

1. The male refers to sex as being so painful to him that he is loath to repeat the experience.  Even when I was a child and first read the story I realized that this was contrary to the human experience and confused me.  It must be important somehow, the point is reiterated 2 or 3 times.  If the girl was purposely making it painful for him the ship should have noticed, since it had already gone through all of this numerous times and should know how sex is done.  In a story this short, items like this should not be present unless they are important to the story.
2. The male frees himself without any help.  he actually caused the short that gives him an excuse to return to the control room weeks before he even met the girl, as he says that the short occurred over three week after he nicked the wire.  The girl was only to be around for 3 weeks and it sounds like it happened after the second day that they are together.  The girl never says anything to him about freeing himself and wouldn't be able to anyway since the ship would hear.  Then after he has freed him self, she claims that she freed him and he acknowledges that she did.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. You are asking 3 questions here; it would be better if you separated them into distinct posts. As it is, this is likely to get closed for being too broad.

Answer (score 2):

About your point number 1, it seems rather obvious that not every single human who experiences sex enjoys it every time.

For example, when a person - male or female, adult or child - is raped, it is usually an emotionally painful experience for them.  And this can make future sexual experiences traumatic for them.

And there is the saying that size matters.  Obviously the male and female organs have to have the proper sizes and shapes relative to each other in order for there to be fertilization, sexual pleasure, or other successful results, thus making sex between members of different intelligent species much less likely than in some science fiction stories.  And that means that some men or women might experience pain during sex with at least one other person if their organs are sufficiently mismatched, and thus be reluctant to try it again with someone else.

There have been many historic marriages where the first known children were not born until a number of years after the marriage.

The future Louis XVI of France was born 23 August 1754 and on 16 May 1770, aged 15 years, 8 months, and 23 days, married Marie Antoinette, born 2 November 1755 and so aged 14 years, 4 months, and 14 days.  Their first child, Marie-Therese-Charlotte, was not born until 19 December 1778, when Louis was 24 years, 3 months, and 26 days old and Marie Antoinette was 23 years, 1 month, and 17 days old.

The reasons for this long delay were discussed at that time and ever since.  One suggestion that is not now accepted is that Louis had phimosis, a condition that can result in pain during an erection.  So whether Louis had phimosis or not, some men do have it and can suffer from painful erections.

Thus there is at least one recognized medical condition than can make sex painful for men.

Of course, since humans are very complex emotionally, there could be other reasons which a male human character might say that sex was painful for him.

Comment: The great mathematician [Paul Erdős](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/people/obituary-paul-erdos-1356495.html) apparently suffered from a similar condition, finding sex painful or at least very unpleasant.